# Изменение рисунка при нажатии

Tags: jquery

Как сделать,  чтобы при нажатии на рисунок, он изменился при помоши функции toggle, вернее, при нажатии он изменил класс? Я использую это для плеера. Спс за помощь.

Comment: @abdujalil Не надо использовать транслит.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#risunok').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
});
```

Comment: Эта функция заменит классы даже если их несколько?

Comment: Не заменит, а "попереключает". Классов может быть несколько и идти они должны через пробел.

Answer (score 2):

- `$('selector').toogleClass('class')` - Добавит класс class если его нет, и  удалит, если он есть. Так же есть методы:
- `$('selector').hasClass('class')` - вернет истину если класс class есть, ложь если нету. Также есть методы:
- `$('selector').addClass('class')` - добавит класс class.
- `$('selector').removeClass('class')` - удалит класс class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).css("property","value"); Установит всем найденным по селектору элементам свойство property:value

$(selector).css("property") //Вернет значение свойства css
```

Функция $.toggle() переключает видимость элемента